# Mapping class group and surgery theory

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mapping-class-groups, cobordism, surgery-theory, kirby-calculus

Given a smooth manifold $M$ of dimension $n$ and a diffeomorphism $\phi: M \to M$, we can construct a smooth cobordism of dimension $(n+1)$ from $M$ to $M$ by gluing $M \times [0,1]$ with itself by $\phi$. However, smooth cobordism of dimension $(n+1)$ is almost the same as surgery theory of dimension $n$. Therefore, I expect a correspondence among

- Surgery theory of dimension $n$ (in particular, its higher Kirby diagrams)
- (Smooth) mapping class group theory for $n$-dimensional manifolds

Has any theory in this line of thought been developed (any reference)?

Comment: Your cobordism is always diffeomorphic to the trivial cobordism by sending $(x,t)$ to $(x,t/2)$ if $t \leq 1$ and to $(\phi^{-1}(x),t/2)$ if $t \geq 1$. You are not wrong to say there is a connection though between surgery theory and mapping class groups, though I think it is much easier to study the components of $\operatorname{Diff(M)}$ with it than the actual mapping class group. Quinn formulated this approach in his paper on surgery spaces.

Comment: Which paper of Quinn did you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to include it: "A geometric formulation of surgery". It is difficult to read in my opinion, so I might recommend reading the intro to section 2 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.04647.pdf . The point being that Quinn's structure space $S(M)$ can be written as a quotient of homotopy automorphisms modulo block diffeomorphisms, both of which are easier to study than $\operatorname{Diff}(M)$ with homotopy theory.

Comment: I don't know how related this is to what you had in mind, but Kreck established something rougly called "bordisms of diffeomorphisms" and these are closely related to mapping tori (i.e. taking $M\times [0,1]$ and gluing the ends together via your diffeomorphism)